# Why a <cite> when I have <em>

Tags: html, semantic-markup

The `<cite>` html element is supposed to convey more semantic information than just using an `<em>`. But what is the core difference in usage and purpose of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<cite>` goes around citations. `<em>` goes around emphasised text. They have totally different semantic meanings to things like search engines and screen readers.

Comment: So does that mean the HTML depends on interpretation of Search Engines... which means that now beyond the issues of Presentation ( solved with CSS ) and Actions ( solved with Javascript ) we need to use tags that have implicit meanings to search engines ?

Comment: Of course. This is hardly new. It's not just for search engines, either. Computers can't figure out what the semantic meaning of a block of code is on their own, hence semantic tags like `cite`, `em`, `h1`, `blockquote`, etc.

Comment: @Icarus: also, if they have different meanings then different browsers might style things differently. Maybe one browser will italicize the text inside a `<cite>` tag but another will just add quotes around that text (like it happens with the `<q>` tag). It doesn't make sense to style the `<em>` tag with quotes, does it?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to imagine a situation in which you want to typeset citations differently from emphasized text. This can be done easily using for instance style sheets thanks to the fact that the tags are different.

Comment: Then, if its about just the CSS, why a tag called cite ? I could have used the same over the em.

Comment: It's not just about the CSS. You could use CSS to replace `blockquote`, `h1`, and many others if that were the only consideration.